# SQLite header and source version mismatch in Linux Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: sqlite, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04

I Have this problem with sqlite3. I am using Linux Ubuntu 12.04 and I can not resolve this
problem
Can Someone help me?
I need use sqlite but I don't know how repair this

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite header and source version mismatch
2011-11-01 00:52:41 c7c6050ef060877ebe77b41d959e9df13f8c9b5e
2014-06-04 14:06:34 b1ed4f2a34ba66c29b130f8d13e9092758019212
```

Comment: If you got the `sqlite3` binary from the distribution, then it's a bug in that package. Did you ever install your own SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem. I found the solution at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443379/sqlite-header-and-source-version-mismatch)
After building the SQLite from source, your head and source are in 2 separate places and have to be adjusted.

your source-location: `/usr/local/lib`

your head-location:  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6` (or `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6` for i386 arch)

just overwrite the head with the source. worked for me :)

```
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
```